# How to convert varchar into time on Redshift- " Column "duration" has unsupported type "time without time zone"

Tags: sql, time, casting, amazon-redshift

I have a column where I time stored as varchar (e.g."00:00:00") and want to CAST or CONVERT it into time which is pretty simple but being new Redshift DB I am struggling with an error that states " Column "duration" has unsupported type "time without time zone".

The commands CAST and Convert works when I am trying to use it on individual strings like `SELECT CAST('09:47:11' AS TIME)` or `SELECT Convert(TIME,'09:47:11')` but not when I am trying to pass an entire column.

Please help me with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is unclear.  Redshift does not have a `time` data type.  Nor, alas, does it have an `interval` data type.  The documentation covers both the supported types and the [differences from Postgres](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-datatypes.html).

I would suggest that you translate the value into a number -- seconds:

```
select (split_part(duration, ':', 1)::int * 60 * 60 +
        split_part(duration, ':', 2)::int * 60 +
        split_part(duration, ':', 3)::int
       ) as seconds_duration
```

Answer (score 0):

try using timestamp

```
   cast(column as timestamp)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: 'interval' type cannot be cast to 'timestamp' in redshift: `cannot cast type interval to timestamp without time zone`